# php multidimensional array search

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

this is the array, how to get the Key of id "573"

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 577 [name] => BPO Manager  ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 578 [name] => BPO User  ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 575 [name] => user2 ) 
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 573 [name] => Site Admin  ) 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Getting it is trivial so what exactly is the problem? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like:

```
$array[0][3]->id;
```

Comment: Don't think thats dyamic enough do you?

Comment: Question is not about accessing `id`.

Comment: You may be right, but the question body is: `this is the array, how to get the Key of id "573"`

Comment: This is a perfect answer. The problem is not with the answer, it is with OP's phrasing of the question.

Comment: Key of `id 573` is **3**. In your answer we already know that key is **3**.

Comment: if ($array[0][3]->id == 573) { return $array[0][3]->name; }

Comment: this array is a dynamically generated array!

Answer (score 0):

```
$key=573;
var_dump(search($arr,573));

function search($yourArray,$key)
{
    foreach($yourArray[0] as $object)
    {
     if ($object->key==$key)
        {
          return $object->id;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Those are objects, not arrays

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $arr1) {
       foreach ($arr1 as $key1 => $obj) {
           if ($obj->id == '573') {
             return $obj->name;
           }
       }
    }
```